# Image is different after exporting in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, reduceregion

(update: I am restateing my problem since I think my last update strayed the question to the matter of geodesic/planner, which could also be one of the causes for the difference, but even after correcting for this, there are still differences)

I look for statistics (min, max, mean, and count) of an image within a region using GEE's `reduceRegion`. I exported the image and looked for the same statistics in GEE, and the results were different. I am not sure why. Here is a reproducible code.

```
var npp = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD17A3HGF")
var vi = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13A1")

var coords = [
  [-150.24259955930222, 28.51681737118324],
  [-72.15177924680223, 28.51681737118324],
  [-72.15177924680223, 61.721035570215975],
  [-150.24259955930222, 61.721035570215975],
  [-150.24259955930222, 28.51681737118324]
]

var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon({
  coords: coords,
  geodesic: false
})

// prepare data: evi, npp, lonLat layer
var evi = vi.select('EVI').filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01').mean()
var npp = npp.select('Npp').filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01').mean()
var lonLat = ee.Image.pixelLonLat()
var data = ee.Image.cat([evi, npp, lonLat])

// reduce to region
var reducers = ee.Reducer.min().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.max(),
  sharedInputs: true
}).combine({
  reducer2:ee.Reducer.mean(),
  sharedInputs: true
}).combine({
  reducer2:ee.Reducer.count(),
  sharedInputs: true
})
var reduceResult = data.toDouble().reduceRegion({
  geometry: geometry,
  reducer: reducers,
  scale: 5000,
  crs: 'EPSG:4269'
})
print(reduceResult)

// export to image
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: data,
  description: 'test_reduceRegion_Export',
  region: geometry,
  scale: 5000,
  crs: 'EPSG:4269'
})
```

and in Python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rasterio

def load_data(path):
  with rasterio.open(path, 'r') as reader:
    data = [reader.read(i) for i in range(1, reader.count + 1)]
  
  data = np.array(data)
  n_bands, n_rows, n_cols = data.shape
  
  data = data.reshape(-1, n_rows * n_cols)
  
  data = data.swapaxes(0, 1)
  
  return data  

data = load_data(path)
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['evi', 'npp', 'lon', 'lat'])
data_df.describe()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the polygon you post, can you edit the post and add `geometrySmall` in geoJSON? I tested it with a rectangular polygon and I got the same result in GGE and QGIS. So maybe the shape of your polygon is affecting the results, I'm thinking in half-pixel inside your polygon or something like that

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try making a reproducible goemetry later when I get home (some 11 hours later) to my laptop. But it may be worth noting that not all of maximum values are different when I try it with other images... Then again the exact pixel values may be different, while the maximum value remains the same. I am not aware of a method to print out all the exact pixel values in GEE. Also, I will try to find some references on how GEE deals with incomplete pixels and see if this is the cause.